# Jquery: Select the next nested input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<td><input class="publish" id="publish_company_ids" name="publish_company_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>

<td><input class="discard" id="discard_company_ids" name="discard_company_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
```

I'd like when I click the first checkbox, the second checkbox to become disabled. I am trying this jquery code:

```
$(".publish").click(function () { 
 $(this).parent().next("td > input[text='checkbox']").css("border","1px solid green");
});
```

I tried by changing css border but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have `text` instead of `type` in your selector.

Second, if that doesn't help, try this:

```
$(this).parent().next('td').children('input:checkbox').css('border','1px solid green');
```

Comment: It worked, just it didn't want the css change (it didn't apply the border), so I replace it with toggle() and it worked. I tried many things but only this one is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow users to select only one of the checkbox then you should radio button instead of checkbox.

Comment: If I add radio buttons, I'll have to add 3 radio, in case someone wants to deselect the option.

Comment: You don't have to add three radio, but you don't need to make any radio selected by default. thats it. You will have three result. one publish_company_ids , discard_company_ids and null, you will not get any value..

Comment: I'll have to add it in case a user accidentally select an option and wants after to deselect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".publish").click(function () { 
 $(this).parent().find("input.discard").css("border","1px solid green");
});
```

Or:

```
$(".publish").click(function () { 
 $(this).parent().children("input.discard").css("border","1px solid green");
});
```